# Lock input field with maximum Characters

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I want to lock the entry of input fields after a maximum number of characters.
I use Google App Engine and this not supports jsf 2.2 and so i can't use HTML5.

I use jsf 2.1 and primefaces 4.0

```
<p:inputText style="width:350px" id="firstname" value="#{regiBean.user.FIRST_NAME}"
    required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['regi_firstname_error']}" >
    <f:validateLongRange maximum="5"/>   
</p:inputText>
```

So I tried it this way but it's not working

here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var firstname;
        function initialize() {
        firstname = document
            .getElementById("regiFrom:firstname");
        firstname.addEventListener("keypress", function(){
            firstname.value = firstname.value.substr(0, 5)
        }, false);
         }          
</script>

<p:inputText style="width:350px" id="firstname" value="#{regiBean.user.FIRST_NAME}"
             required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['regi_firstname_error']}"/>
```

Comment: No context or code or fiddles...

Answer (score 1):

Where the myInputElement is the input you're keeping shortened, and maxLength is the char #:

```
myInputElement.addEventListener("keypress", function(){
    myInputElement.value = myInputElement.value.substr(0, maxLength);
}, false);
```

Comment: try to use it  and then answer

Comment: I can i set the maxlength attribute with the following code?
<p:inputText>
<f:validateLongRange minimum="1" 
maximum="5"/>       
</p:inputText>
?

Answer (score 0):

Solution with Primefaces ; the p:inputText Tag has a maxlength attribute

```
<p:inputText style="width:350px" id="lastname" value="#{regiBean.user.LAST_NAME}"
    required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['regi_lastname_error']}" maxlength="5" />
```